# Rosdep install error

Tags: ros, ethzasl-icp-mapping, rosdep-install

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After I downloaded the git from ethzasl_icp_mapping website, I executed  the commands:

```
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:`pwd`/ethzasl_icp_mapping
rosdep install ethzasl_icp_mapping
```

then I got problem as following:

```
stephan@stephan-VPCSD300C:~$ rosdep install ethzasl_icp_mapping
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
ethzasl_icp_mapper: Missing resource map_msgs
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/groovy/share
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/groovy/stacks
ROS path [3]=/home/stephan/groovy_workspace/sandbox/ethzasl_icp_mapping
```

could anyone teach me how to overcome this, please?THX!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57382/rosdep-install-error/) by [Shifaye](https://answers.ros.org/users/4374/shifaye/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Likely there is something wrong with the `map_msgs` package in `rosdep`.  I would say the quickest way for you to solve your problem is to clone the `map_msgs` package then make sure it is in your $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, and then build it.

```
cd /home/stephan/groovy_workspace/sandbox
git clone https://github.com/ethz-asl/map_msgs
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:$(pwd)/map_msgs
cd map_msgs
rosmake
```

This should allow you to execute their final instruction `rosmake ethzasl_icp_mapping`

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2013-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-03-07**:
Yes, you need to have all ROS dependencies installed to be able to rosdep install a package.

**Comment by [Shifaye](https://answers.ros.org/users/4374/shifaye/) on 2013-03-08**:
THX a lot, Already solved!